# Ribbon Load Balancer cannot see list of servers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am playing around with SprinG Cloud 1.0.0.M3. I have my Eureka as well as my configuration servers work. I also have two microservices: fancyserver and fancyribbon. The server code is the standard Hello World:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@EnableEurekaClient
public class Application {
@RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return "Hello World ";
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

The fancyribbon code is also simple. It tries to discover fancyserver and return its result:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@EnableEurekaClient
public class RibbonClient {
  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    return restTemplate;
  }
  public void setRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }
 @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return getRestTemplate().getForObject("http://fancyserver", String.class).toString() ;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RibbonClient.class, args);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The ribbon client cannot see the list of servers. That means it is not seeing fancyserver. I know however that both fancyserver and fancy client are registered with Eureka. I can see them under the address of my eureka server:

```
http://localhost:7001/eureka/apps
```

Edit: The eureka output can be seen on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/vua8f4XR

I also tried to manually invoke the load balancer:

```
 ServiceInstance instance = loadBalancer.choose("fancyserver");
 fancyServerUri= URI.create(String.format("http://%s:%s", instance.getHost(), instance.getPort()));
```

This results in the same error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate ILoadBalancer for service: fancyserver
>   No up servers available from load balancer: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=fancyserver,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList@6a8dcefd

My application.yml configurations are pretty simple. For fancyserver:

```
server:
   port: 9002
eureka:
  instance:
    virtualHostName: fancyserver
    appGroupName: fancyGroup
```

For fancyribbon:

```
server:
   port: 9003
eureka:
  instance:
     virtualHostName: fancyribbon
     appGroupName: fancyGroup
  client:
     region: default
     registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 5
     availabilityZones:
         default: ${APPLICATION_DOMAIN:${DOMAIN:defaultZone}}
```

The bootstrap.yml and similarly simple. For fancyserver:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: fancyserver
    cloud:
        config:
            uri: http://localhost:8888
```

And for fancyribbon:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: fancyribbon
    cloud:
        config:
            uri: http://localhost:8888
```

I wonder what am I missing. Why isn't fancyribbon seeing fancyserver?

Edit: The config server includes among other things, the link to eureka:

```
eureka:
    instance:
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:7001/eureka/
```

Comment: I can't see a `eureka.client.serviceUrl` (maybe it's in the config server)?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I edited the post to include the serviceUrl. And yes, you are right, it is in the config file served by the config server.

Comment: Can you try with snapshots? Spencer noticed earlier this week there was a weird effect if the local network has a domain (eg you have local DNS or a route that adds a fake domain that isn't present on the localhost lookup). I think we fixed it for him.

Comment: Oh wow. Mucho appreciated. 1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT works. Is the fix going to go into M3?

Comment: That's not the way releases work (M3 is already built and deployed). There's an RC1 coming up though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with snapshots? Spencer noticed earlier this week there was a weird effect if the local network has a domain (eg you have local DNS or a route that adds a fake domain that isn't present on the localhost lookup). I think we fixed it for him.